# Best approach to create manager in Swift using singleton pattern

Tags: swift, swift3, singleton

I have two examples of simple manager in our application.

```
enum SomeStatus {
   case none
   case inProgress
}

class SomeManager {
   static let shared = SomeManager()

   private var _status: SomeStatus = .none

   var status: SomeStatus {
      get { return _status }
   }

   func changeStatus(to status: SomeStatus) {
      _status = status
   }

}

let manager = SomeManager.shared
print (manager.status)

// none

manager.changeStatus(to: .inProgress)
print (manager.status)

// inProgress
```

In this example I hide possibility to change status outside our manager with directly assign status variable. Anyway looks good.

But we can do this another way

```
class SomeManager {
   private static let shared = SomeManager()

   private var _status: SomeStatus = .none

   static var status: SomeStatus {
      get { return shared._status }
   }

   static func changeStatus(to status: SomeStatus) {
          shared._status = status
       }

}

print (SomeManager.status)

// none

SomeManager.changeStatus(to: .inProgress)
print (SomeManager.status)

// inProgress
```

The point to show how we can hide shared instance at all, but using same pattern of singleton

So, the question is, what is best performance/approach to use cases in example?

Comment: What is the purpose of preventing the direct write access to the property?

Comment: @MartinR, first, its encapsulation and control variable in the future. Yes, we can use observer property, but for me it's more clean way.

Comment: You can also "control variable in the future" with a normal public property. You generally don't need to write separate setters and getters in swift.

Comment: @Sweeper what you say, if our property has many different logic, it this case status have only two cases, but what you say if status will have 20 cases for example, and in some cases we don't need to change status at all. We can discuss this in another branch. The question is, using directly shared instance or using static methods with shared instance inside method.